# codeigniter get data via ajax and json from db

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have following problem:

View:

```
<script>
        function show(id) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('index.php/controller/show_id'); ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:({id: id}),
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert( data.user_id);
                }

            });
        }

        </script>
```

Controller:

```
function show_id(){

            $id= $this->input->post('id');
            $id_list = $this->id_model->show_id($id);   
            $data['id'] = $id_list;
            if($data['id']){   
                 echo json_encode( $data['id'] );
            } else {
                 echo json_encode( array('error' => true) );
            }   
        }
```

If I load the page, I got "undefined" as an alert.
If I change the JS to "alert(data);" I receive all content of the sql table. 
How do I have to change the JS to get only "user.id" column?

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` instead of `alert`, what does the structure look like? You may be able to discern the correct access path, or if something unexpected is being returned by the server.

Comment: Well if i use `console.log(data)` I get few Objects (with the data like in the sql table), if I change to `console.log(data.user_id)` I receive again "undefined. I thought with data.user_id I would receive all user_id's like in the DB or am I wrong?

Comment: @flips123 Is `data` a single user, or multiple users? `data.user_id` would look for the property `user_id` on `data`. If `data` is actually a list of objects that *each* have `user_id`, you would need to take the first one or loop or something depending on your goal. The output from `console.log` should show you the structure of the data, and you can use that to determine what "path" through the data structure you need to take.

Comment: data should be several users who all have the same id (not user_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check type of data like that `alert(typeof data);` `if it`s get string then you need to convert your response in object and you can convert your response in object like that --

`var result = JSON.parse(data);`

and you are getting a single row or multiple rows ?????  if you are getting a single row then after convert in object you have to access `data.user_id` like that (after convert into object) --

```
var userId = result[0]['user_id];
```

please try this..

Comment: `alert(typeof data)` gives object

Comment: then get user id like that 
var userId = data[0]['user_id];

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because the index user_id is not found in data. you have too loop through the array first and then you can get value of data.user_id
see below.

```
success: function (data) {
   var data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(data);
   for (var x in data){
       console.log(data[x].user_id);
   }    
}
```

Comment: gives me "5 undefined"

Comment: can you paste the result of your query?

Comment: Result: `[{"user_id":"14","id":"4","us_user_id":"1001","us_date":"2015-07-31","us_time":"03:15:00","us_here":"0","us_text":"Test","us_notes":"test"},{"user_id":"17","id":"4","us_user_id":"1002","us_date":"2015-07-31","us_time":"04:00:00","us_here":"0","us_text":"mkmkmkmkm","us_notes":""},{"user_id":"16","id":"4","us_user_id":"1002","us_date":"2015-07-25","us_time":"02:30:00","us_here":"0","us_text":"Test Test Test","us_notes":""}]`